# How do I autofill down to last row when I'm not starting in a specific cell reference?

Tags: vba, excel

Following on from [Search column headers and insert new column using Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42439988/search-column-headers-and-insert-new-column-using-excel-vba) I wish to ask a further question.

I'm up to here:

```
Dim rngUsernameHeader As Range
Dim rngHeaders As Range

Set rngHeaders = Range("1:1") 'Looks in entire first row.
Set rngUsernameHeader = rngHeaders.Find(what:="Username", After:=Cells(1, 1))

rngUsernameHeader.Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Insert
rngUsernameHeader.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Role"
rngUsernameHeader.Offset(1, 1).Value = "=VLOOKUP(K2,Role!A:B,2,0)"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range ???
```

My issue with the vlookup(as the lookup value might not always be in column K) and also specifying the range on the last line. I was previously using:

```
Selection.Autofill Destination:=Range("L2:L" & LastRow)
```

As "Role" was in column L on my test data and the lookup value is in Username column. This is beyond my knowledge of VBA!

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you are asking - it's not clear to me?

Comment: @GrahamMcCubbin it seems what you need does not need to be necessarily done the way you think. As SJR mentioned, we have no idea what exactly you need to do

Comment: The main query was in the link of the first question I asked, then this second question became apparent.