# Search column headers with OptionButton and insert new column using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, search, insert, radio-button

Hi guys I´m new at VBA programming and have some difficulties...

I have an UserForm with OptionButtons. So what I want is, when  i Click on a OptionButton, the code will search in the Columns in Tabell2 and when found, insert a new Column ToLeft.

My code is obviously wrong and/or bad written...

```
Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
  Dim cl As Range
  If OptionButton1.Value = True Then Search "10700"
  For Each cl In Worksheets("Tabelle2").Range("1:1")
  If cl = "10700" Then cl.EntireColumn.Activate
  End If
  End Sub

Private Sub AddColumn()
  Dim cl As Range

  For Each cl In Worksheets("Dokumentenübersicht").Range("1:1")
    If cl = Active Then
       cl.EntireColumn.Insert Shift:=xlToLeft
    End If

    cl.Offset(0, 1) = "role"
Next cl
End Sub
```

Comment: If done some research and found the quite simular question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42439988/search-column-headers-and-insert-new-column-using-excel-vba      But with Combine the optionBox it´s something different. So I tried to activate the Column and the insert next to the active column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be working between different sheets but here is a general outline.

The following assumes you are both searching and inserting in `Worksheets("Tabelle2")`.

It uses the `Range.Find` method to locate the string of interest. The range to search is currently set at row 1 as per your code.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
    Dim cl As Range
    If  OptionButton1 Then
        Set cl = Worksheets("Tabelle2").Range("1:1").Find("10700")
        If Not cl Is Nothing Then cl.EntireColumn.Insert Shift:=xlToLeft
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It works! Thank you verry much!!! I´m now a step forward and can continue to work with it!